# Why did the Egyptians not represent $2/3$ as a sum of unit fractions in the Rhind papyrus?

Tags: math-history, conjectures, divisor-sum, perfect-numbers, egyptian-fractions

The following is taken verbatim from the [MathWorld Wolfram page on Egyptian fractions](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/EgyptianFraction.html):

> An Egyptian fraction is a sum of positive (usually) distinct unit fractions.  The famous Rhind papyrus, dated to around 1650 BC contains a table of representations of $2/n$ as Egyptian fractions for odd $n$ between $5$ and $101$.  ... The unique fraction that the Egyptians did not represent using unit fractions was $2/3$ (**The Penguin Dictionary of Curious and Interesting Numbers**, Wells 1986, p. 29).

Well, I kind of find this surprising, since it is relatively easy to compute
$$\frac{2}{3}=\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{6},$$
which, according to the [cited webpage [equation (4)]](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/EgyptianFraction.html), can be obtained using the greedy algorithm.

I checked the Wells reference, and it only has the following story to tell:

> $2/3$ - The uniquely unrepresentative "Egyptian" fraction, since the Egyptians used only unit fractions, with this one exception.  All other fractional quantities were expressed as sums of unit fractions.

I know that the answer to this question may be covered in some *History of Mathematics* book, but I currently do not have the expertise to gauge which authoritative sources to check.

**MOTIVATION**

It is currently unknown whether there is a number $m$ such that
$$I(m) = \frac{\sigma(m)}{m} = \frac{5}{3} = 1 + \frac{2}{3},$$
where $I$ is the *abundancy index* and $\sigma$ is the *sum-of-divisors* function.  If such a number $m$ exists, then $5m$ is an [odd perfect number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perfect_number#Odd_perfect_numbers), where $5 \nmid m$.

> *For more information on the exact connection between the Egyptian fraction decomposition of $1$ with odd denominators, and odd perfect numbers, I refer the interested reader to the following [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3594275/28816) to a closely related question by [MSE user Thomas Bloom](https://math.stackexchange.com/u/870).*

Comment: About the last sentence: This is only if $5\not\mid m$, right?

Comment: @joriki, yes it can be proved that if
$$I(m)=\frac{\sigma(m)}{m}=\frac{5}{3}=1+\frac{2}{3},$$
then $3 \mid m$ and $5 \nmid m$.  In fact, it is easy to show that $m$ would be a square.

Comment: @joriki, I have added your condition to the question to make it more explicit.

Comment: Curiously, [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rhind_Mathematical_Papyrus#Book_I_%E2%80%93_Arithmetic_and_Algebra) states:

**The first part of the papyrus is taken up by the $2/n$ table. The fractions $2/n$ for odd $n$ ranging from $3$ to $101$ are expressed as sums of unit fractions.**

I do wonder whether that $3$ is a typo.

Comment: Further down in the [Content section of that Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rhind_Mathematical_Papyrus#Content):

**Also bear in mind that the fraction 2/3 is the single exception, used in addition to integers, that Ahmes uses alongside all (positive) rational unit fractions to express Egyptian fractions.**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They had a special symbol for 2/3, presumably because of frequent use, so there was no need to work out its representation.  See chapter 7 of Annette Imhausen's *Mathematics in Ancient Egypt: A Contextual History*, Princeton University Press, 2016.

Comment: Thank you for this answer, @BrianHopkins!  Just what I needed.  +1!  =)

Comment: +1. I was tempted to suggest it may be omitted because 2/3=1/2+1/6 was so well-known, just as a reference manual of indefinite  integrals might omit $\int Kdx=Kx+C.$

Answer (score 2):

The first fractions Ancient Egyptians used were $\frac{1}{2}$, $\frac{1}{3}$, $\frac{2}{3}$, $\frac{1}{4}$ and $\frac{3}{4}$. They used special words for these *natural fractions*.

As techniques of calculation developed unit fractions were introduced. Notation was concise **except** previously established symbols for natural fractions. Since $\frac{2}{3}$ and $\frac{3}{4}$ already had designators, these weren't broken down into unit fractions. Egyptians just continued using them in the old way. Nevertheless, after some time, $\frac{3}{4}$ began to be expressed like other fractions, but somehow $\frac{2}{3}$ remained a exception.

I based my answer Chapter I. The Egyptians from Waerden, B. L. van der. (1988). *Science awakening*. Dordrecht, The Netherlands: Kluwer Academic Publishers and https://www.bibalex.org.

P.S. It's a curious thing to see what we are talking about. Ancient Egyptians wrote unit fractions by placing ovals (not "1") above numbers. Below regular $\frac{1}{12}$.

[image: 1/12]

And here are the exceptional $\frac{1}{2}$, $\frac{2}{3}$, $\frac{1}{4}$, $\frac{3}{4}$ and normalized $\frac{3}{4}$ respectively.

[image: 1/2], [image: 2/3], [image: 1/4], [image: 3/4], [image: 3/4 normalized]

Comment: Thank you for this insightful answer, @CaptchaSamurai!  +1.  =)